# Can't send AT commands to Bluetooth module with UART interface

Tags: bluetooth, at-command, uart, cts

I want to change the pairing code of a device. It's a chinese clone of a MiniELM327 adapter with a Bluetooth interface. If I power it up through its OBD2 connector supplying 12V, the whole device is on. Through the Bluetooth Serial Port I can communicate with the ELM327 chip and send AT Commands, receiving correct answers.

But that is not what I want to do. I want to change the pairing code of the bluetooth interface itself.

The module is a RG-BT10-10 from Redgoo based on a Beken BK3211 chip. I have the datasheet and the command set (not sure if it's the right one). Unfortunately it is all in chinese and the customer support is in chinese too (they use automatic translators).

www . redgoo.com.cn/product/20131106105822750.pdf

www . redgoo.com.cn/product/20131130122844243.pdf

www . belon.cn/Uploadfiles/psd/BK3211datasheetv1.2.pdf

I tried to contact the manufacturer and they said that I have to send the following commands:

```
AT+EN1 (enter command mode)
AT+PIN****
AT+EN0 (exit command mode)
```

and then reset the module.

I bought a ftdi-based USB-to-UART converter at denkovi.com

www . denkovi.com/usb-to-uart-ftdi-serial-interface-adaptor

Then I wired the pins on the USB-to-UART with the corresponding contacts on the RG-BT10-10 (Tx and Rx are switched of course).

According to the datasheets, the parameters are:

Baud Rate: 38400

Parity: None

Data bits: 8

Stop bit: 1

And the AT commands should be terminated with \r\n that is CR+LF if I'm not mistaken.

No information on flow control. The RTS pin on the board is not even soldered, meaning that it's not used during device normal operation.

From here on, I'm lost. I tried with several programs (Hyperterminal, Putty, Tera Term etc.) to send the AT command which should yield an "OK" but no response has ever arrived.

To be clear, if I fiddle with the wires (like grounding and releasing RTS or turning the RG-BT10-10 on and off) I sometimes get some chars so the flow of data from the module to the computer physically works.

Is there some basic theory I'm missing? I can't get enough information from the manufacturer (language barriers...). And I believe that I have all the hardware that I need, so I just have to understand how to set it correctly :)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly your problem.  No response to AT from PuTTY or HyperTerminal at 9600 Baud (which is correct/default for the SPP-CA).

All I would see is:

```
+READY
+PAIRABLE
```

when powering up.

I then tried the Serial Monitor that comes with the Arduino IDE, www .arduino.cc/download_handler.php?f=/arduino-1.6.7-windows.exe.  Changed line endings to "Both NL & CR" and at 9600 Baud, it came to life:

```
AT
OK
AT+VERSION
+VERSION=+BOLUTEK Firmware V2.2, Bluetooth V2.1
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: wow, a response :D Can you please list your exact hardware setup?

Comment: Most probably @user3761063 has a working breakout board that allows him/her to communicate with the bare module. If you don't, you need to build or use sth like this: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/unknown-bluetooth-module-with-bk3231-chip.123933/#post-1213688

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Putty to send
Ctrl+M : Carriage Return(“\r”)
Ctrl+J : Line Feed(“\n”)

This worked for me in getting a response:
AT [CTRL-J]
OK